# HTACCESS works on APACHE, but not FastCGI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I'm not an expert on htaccess, but here's my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php\/$1\/? [L,QSA]

# disallow directory browsing
Options All -Indexes 

# disallow browsing through the below folders
RedirectMatch 403 \/(config|Library|templates)\/.*
</IfModule>
```

Now, it works just fine on my localhost and apache servers, but my shared server is fastcgi and I can't get it to work, as it keeps returning "No input specified".

Any suggestion on how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you mean Nginx? FastCGI also exists in Apache.

Comment: describe your entire stack.. 
nginx + fastcgi or
apache + fastcgi ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was Nginx at first, but it's actually Apache + Fastcgi with PHP 7.0.32.
Which makes me even more confuse as to why this htaccess isn't working here.